# Custom 18650 lithium ion charger using PWM to control output current - is it safe?

Tags: microcontroller, battery-charging, pwm, lithium-ion, charger

I am trying to design a custom charger for 18650 lithium-ion battery in 4S configuration. Custom in the sense that it could be programmed to vary its output current. The goal is to build a charger that could charge a range of 4S configurations, for example, a 4S1P to 4S8P battery packs. A simplified diagram is provided below:

[image]

Suppose i use a 6A power source. If the battery pack has 4S2P configuration, i could press some buttons on the charger to set it to that configuration and the charger would output only 2A max current. Similarly, if the battery configuration is 4S4P or 4S8P, i would press some buttons and the charger would output 3A or 6A max current respectively.

The problem is that i only know of a single method to control the output current, that is PWM. I do understand that i can control the average output current using the PWM duty cycle. So if choose a 33% duty cycle i almost achieve an output of around 2A.

My question is that although above mentioned duty cycle (33%) would provide a 2A output current (supposing a 6A source) to charge the 4S2P battey pack, is it really safe? I mean the "pulse" mechanism of PWM does reduce the average output but not the actual output. I mean the "pulse" will still push the maximum current (6A) for a certain period of time.

So i actually have two questions:

1. Is this (PWM) method safe for such a scenario? I mean can i use PWM to charge a 4S2P battery pack using a 6A power source using 33% (approx.) duty cycle and stay assured that it is safe? I am kind of repeating my self here but my concern is that even after using the PWM duty cycle, the microcontroller will still push full 6A pulses for brief periods. Are those pulses "normal" or would these damage the battery? If this is not safe, what alteration can be made to make it safe or is this method not usable at all in this scenario?
2. Is there any other feasible alternate way to control the charging current, for example, getting a range of actual output current (not average) from 1A to 6A? If there is, please point me to a relevant resource so that i can dig further.

Comment: Hmm.  A microcontroller is within the realm of what can safely charge li-ion batteries, but if you want to build your own charger circuit, first you should research the charging stages of lithium ion batteries.  I haven't gone looking for them in months but there's a lot of materials describing how to charge lithium ion safely.  You shouldn't skip understanding any part of the circuit.  One other piece of food for thought, if you design your own, do your best to figure out how to make it fail safe.  That means break in a way that doesn't explode the battery.

Comment: @KH Indeed this is a very complex subject and I have researched for quite some time about the charging stages (Pre-Conditioning/CC/CV) as well as fail safe mechanisms like the charge termination current, temperature detection, timer to eliminate indefinite charging etc. But right now i am just worried about controlling the charging current and the "pulse" of the PWM ;) so that i can be sure i am moving in the right direction.

Comment: You won't do as good a job as an engineer, but it's important you do the best you can.  Examples are things like having an appropriate pull up/pull down resistor on a mosfet gate so it doesn't start conducting if the control fails or adding a fuse just above the highest possible output current.  An extension of that would be to use a separate fused output for each charging current level to keep the fuse values closer.

Comment: Thanks @KH i will surely take care of these things once i start to finalize the design

Comment: Have you checked out [the article about it on battery university](https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries)?  They have a chart there that shows you the relationships.  In stage 1, you slowly increase voltage to maintain constant current.  When you reach stage 2 you'll have to switch to PWM to limit current while keeping constant voltage until current falls to <3% of rated, then switch off with an optional periodic topping charge.  This means you need a voltage controlled voltage converter to control voltage and a separate PWM stage to limit charging current.

Comment: @KH That is exactly what i am asking. Since i need to maintain constant current in the first stage and i need it to be programmable (for 4s1p/4s2p/4s3p upto 4s8p), i cannot use a fixed cc circuit. So i am planning to use PWM for maintaining constant current. But since PWM can provide the desired output current using "averaging", is it safe to pump high current pulses(like 6A source for 4S1P) using appropriately calculated PWM duty cycle. The question is about the pulses being safe or not and whether there is any alternate method to control the actual current rather than average.

Comment: During the first stage, pulsing is not acceptable, so you need a PWM circuit with a filter on the output, which is another name for a voltage converter.  Controlling that PWM signal, call it PWM1, will allow you to control voltage.  Phase 1 *must* be a smart voltage converter, meaning it will maintain the correct voltage as load current changes.  Phase 2 requires constant voltage and current control.  The only way to control current while using constant voltage is to pulse it, so in this phase you use a separate PWM signal, call it PWM2, to limit current.

Comment: If you are worried about the amplitude of your filter pulses you could use a filter inductor in series. Choosing a good frequency and value would give you a good compromise in current ripple (step down regulators do exactly that). However I think that there are many other issues in lithium charging as already commented. I would stick to a commercial battery charging IC if possible

Comment: You can't use a fixed "cc" circuit at all because in phase 2 the current has to naturally drop off, and a constant current circuit would increase voltage to maintain the current, no doubt damaging the device.

Comment: PWM with a filter (inductor and capacitor) is more like a voltage source than a current source. It is definitely possible, though, with microcontroller in the circuit, to use PWM with filter to charge a battery pack. You need a way to sense the charge current and the charge voltage. The current sensing needs to be somewhat accurate and the voltage sensing needs to be very accurate. Probably better than 1%. All this can be done with a microcontroller with ADC inputs and some additional circuitry.

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio Could you please point me to a charging IC which can be used in my scenario. I mean which can be programmed for different parallel configurations like 4s1p 4s2p 4s4p etc.

Comment: @mkeith if the PWM frequency was high enough the output cap might be small enough that you could just turn the converter on and off at a lower frequency to pulse the constant voltage maybe?  Is that the idea?  I haven't gotten much above 50khz yet so my converters would have a hard time doing that I think.

Comment: If the L is big enough to keep ripple current low enough (like ripple current is 50 percent or less of the target current, let us say) then a buck converter in the steady state will have this property: Vout = D * Vin. So that is why I say it is more like a voltage supply. But by slowly ramping up the duty cycle while also watching output current, the micro-controller can set the current for the battery to the target level.

Comment: @mkeith What is the alternate (and most appropriate) way to control current other than using PWM?

Comment: I guess we need to be careful about terms here. The best way to do what you want is to build a buck converter (MOSFET + LC output filter) and use the PWM output of the microcontroller to turn the MOSFET on and off. The output current will not be pulsed. It will have some ripple, but will not turn on and off fully each cycle. The filter will smooth it out. Also, you need voltage and current monitoring.

Comment: Thanks @mkeith. It makes sense to me now.